# where can I find free corpus of spoken disabled people (in english, italian)

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, resource-request

I am working on the research project in NLP domain. Basically, we are looking for a free audio corpus of spoken disabled people to study (for instance, aged people, or people has difficulty in normal daily communication due to experienced with psychological, neurological, sensorial, or body problem). Can anyone point me out how to get a possible free public corpus of spoken disable people (audio corpus of disabled people in Italian is preferred, but not limited with English, French, Germain)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a corpus of [alcoholic speech](https://www.phonetik.uni-muenchen.de/forschung/abgeschlossene_projekte/alc_speech.html) hosted by Bayerisches Archiv für Sprachsignale, a [CLARIN-D centre,](https://www.clarin-d.net/de/) that may meet your requirements. The corpus is usable free of charge for academic research and accessible via federated login from many European universities. When you are located outside the federation, you need to apply for a password.